# Copy/Paste Range With One Side Locked Cell and Using Date Find Row Number

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to copy/paste a range of data from column A through column F. I want to have one side of the range locked on A2 and the other side would search in column B for a date specified in H2. While searching for the date in Column B, I want it to return something that would look like F130. That way App Script could Copy/Paste that range making those numbers not editable as I change a cell that before would have changed everything prior to that date as well.

I would like it to be through A2:F3995.

```
 function myFunction1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:F3995').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:F3995').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B1').activate();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const dt = new Date(sh.getRange('H2'));
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  for(let i =0;i<vs.length; i++){
    cdt = new Date(vs[i][1]);
    cdtv = new Date(cdt.getFullYear(), cdt.getMonth(), cdt.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(cdtv = dtv) {
      sh.getRange(2,1,i+2,6).copyTo(sh.getRange(2,1,i+2,6),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```